# How to choose thread/process priority in real-time Linux?

Tags: linux, process, real-time, thread-priority

I am developing real-time software that will run on Linux with the `PREEMPT_RT` patch. While this will let me get realtime performance by using the Linux realtime schedulers (`SCHED_RR` or `SCHED_FIFO`), I am unsure what priority values I should use for my threads. On my system, when I look at the priorities I see (only showing processes with `RTPRIO`):

```
$ ps -e -o cmd,pri,rtprio
CMD                         PRI RTPRIO
[sirq-high/0]                89     49
[sirq-timer/0]               89     49
[sirq-net-tx/0]              89     49
[sirq-net-rx/0]              89     49
[sirq-block/0]               89     49
[sirq-block-iopo]            89     49
[sirq-tasklet/0]             89     49
[sirq-sched/0]               89     49
[sirq-hrtimer/0]             89     49
[sirq-rcu/0]                 89     49
[posixcputmr/0]             139     99
[events/0]                   41      1
[irq/17-systemac]            90     50
[irq/19-watchdog]            90     50
[irq/18-eth0]                90     50
[irq/16-serial]              90     50
```

I have two questions:

1. What are all these `sirq`, `irq`, `posixcputmr` tasks? Kernel threads?
2. At what priority should I make my software run? Should I be running at a higher priority than most of these system threads (>50 or even 99), or lower (<49)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are all these sirq, irq, posixcputmr tasks? Kernel threads?

Yes, all the tasks in brackets are kernel threads.

> At what priority should I make my software run?

From 2-69 for normal RT, and 90-98 for your very high priority application threads. The latter will block all IRQ handlers, so try to do as little as possible at high priority. [Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html-single/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/index.html)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the reference!